# Customising tinymce with React

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I am using the react component of tinymce. The docs are very brief about using tinymce with react and customising it. I am able to include the component but I would like to customise(with css) it. Any help is appreciated. If it is not possible to customise it, could someone suggest an alternative or a way to implement it on my own.

Comment: Customize as in? TinyMCE has many plugins that you can look into.

Comment: No I mean i would like to style it through css

Comment: I've used content_css for such things. Check out my answer, I hope you'll find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option called `content_css` that enables you to style according to the surrounding context. You can read about it more by navigating to this [link](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css). Note that you can use an external CSS file or you can use inline CSS.

From the [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/),

> It is usually desirable that TinyMCE’s editable area has the same
> styling as the surrounding content. Consistent styling is achieved
> with the content_css option, which enables you to extend external CSS
> into the editable area.

Ps. I've assumed that you have used the latest version of TinyMCE (v5)

Comment: how am I supposed to style without classes? There is no info on default classes nor is there an option to add custom sizes